# Excel - how to sum values in one columns based on set of matching rows in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 3 columns: Class ID, Status, Count

I need sum of Count column (in new column), for every row that has same Class ID. I have tried SUMIF but I do not know how to check previous row value.

So if data is:
- A1, ENRL, 2
- A1, COMP, 10
- B1, ENRL, 3
- B1, COMP, 4

Output is
A1, ENRL, 2,  12
A1, COMP, 10, 12
B1, ENRL, 3,   7
B1, COMP, 4,   7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your columns are in A, B, and C and start on row 2, this would be the formula for D2:

=SUMIF($A$2:$A$5,A2,$C$2:$C$5)

Comment: This is giving me the sums as 12, 10, 7, 4

Comment: Did you "drag-fill" it down?  The A2 should be A3 on row 3.  http://i.imgur.com/cABH91i.jpg

Comment: I would imagine you don't have the $ signs.  These lock your reference so it always looks at the same range.  check if cell D5 is =SUMIF(A5:A8,A2,C5:C8), which wouldn't give you the right answer.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I was missing dollar signs. Now first formula is SUMIF($A:$A,$A2,$C:$C)  and I dragged that down.